# MYSQL foreign key problems

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

I'm trying to set a foreign key, and running into issues (and getting the very helpful 1064 "you did something wrong" error)

Code to create:

```
CREATE TABLE `airport`(
`id` int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`rwyCount` int,
`lat` float(4),
`lon` float(4),
`type` int, 
FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES apType(id),
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The only way I can get it to not give me that error is by removing the foreign key line.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code for the apType table, very simple one:

```
CREATE TABLE `apType`(
`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: remove the comma at the end of the foreign key line

Comment: Full error would have been helpful additionally ;-)

Comment: removed the comma and got: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES apType(id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 8

Comment: its fixed.  Looks like that when i removed the extra comma, I copied in a version that didn't have type after foreign key.  Thank you

Comment: @Gryphius put the first comment as answer so he can accept it

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys - so there is point in defining them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enforce foreign key constraints, you need to use Innodb rather than MyISAM. [MyISAM parses and then ignores foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html).

> For storage engines other than InnoDB, MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN
>   KEY syntax in CREATE TABLE statements, but does not use or store it.

You also need to [declare either a primary key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) or a unique constraint on the referenced column. (The "id" column here.)

> ...the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced
>   columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key
>   references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not
>   well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are
>   advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including
>   PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys.

```
CREATE TABLE `apType`(
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

On MySQL, you're better off not trying to declare primary key constraints inline.

```
CREATE TABLE `airport`(
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rwyCount` int,
  `lat` float(4),
  `lon` float(4),
  `type` int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES apType(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```